# about the name of the function f(1/x)

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

Suppose we have f(x) as a function. Then, what do you call f(1/x)? I am looking for the correct technical English term.
Thanks

Comment: I doubt that such a term (or expression) exists.

Comment: It is still "the same" function $f$. Do you mean perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305798/what-is-the-name-of-the-function-fx-frac1x/305814)? You could compose it first with this function $g(x)=1/x$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde, No, I mean the function with the reciprocal input. How do we say it formally in a math paper? thanks

Comment: $f$ applied to $g$, where $g(x)=1/x$. No name really, as already remarked in the question linked. For a polynomial there is a name, by the way, if we consider $g(x)=x^nf(1/x)$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963477/prove-that-the-polynomial-xnf1-x-with-reverted-coefficients-is-also-irreduc). It is called *reciprocal polynomial*.

Comment: Isn't $f(1/x)$ already a convenient name?